# Azure Mobile Apps with Cordova/Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am evaluating Azure's Mobile Apps and I want to clarify my findings.

Azure Mobile Apps do not support Cordova/Ionic database offline sync. Is this coming soon or not considered?

Are there any hacks or workarounds to solve this for now?

Comment: StackOverflow is targeted at technical questions and solutions. For specific feature requests, etc., please use a communication vehicle specific to the product in question. In this case, the Azure Mobile forums would be appropriate: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=azuremobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently working towards Offline Sync capabilities within the Cordova / JavaScript world.  Once it's ready to release, we will release on npmjs.com and tag the release in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client).  You can also check the [pure JS client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client) on GitHub.  Both will be updated and released once ready.

Comment: It's now on RC1 :)